# Using Angular constant to declare controller names

Tags: javascript, angularjs, constants, angularjs-controller

I am trying to declare constants for all string values I use in my Angular project. My sample code looks like below,

```
//create module
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//define constants for controller names
myApp.constant("CONTROLLERS", {
    "LOGIN_CONTROLLER" : "loginCtrl",
    "HOME_PAGE_CONTROLLER" : "homePageCtrl"
});
```

Now, while creating controllers in the respective controller files, I use the below code,

```
myApp.controller(CONTROLLERS.LOGIN_CONTROLLER, function(){.....});
```

When I execute my application, I get the below error during the loading of my loginCtrl.js file,

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: CONTROLLERS is not defined"

Am I using the Angular constants in a wrong way?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try it like this instead myApp.controller('CONTROLLERS.LOGIN_CONTROLLER',function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Angular constants can only be injected into angular functions

```
directive('foo', function(CONTROLLERS){});
```

They are not usable outside injection.

Are you trying to use constants because you are adverse to leaving the directive names as strings? Using strings is fine because if the directive name ever changed you would have bigger issues.

Is there instead some other problem you are trying to solve by using constants?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to declare the constants as a plain javascript variable:

```
var CONTROLLERS = {

    "LOGIN_CONTROLLER" : "loginCtrl",
    "HOME_PAGE_CONTROLLER" : "homePageCtrl"
}
```

In this way your code could work.

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/43fu3poz/